# How do the cell walls contain contents moving such high speeds?

Tags: biophysics

Inside cells, a lot of things are moving at an amazing speed. But when things move at such a speed, they have a lot of kinetic energy which can increase temperature etc.

If you think of a room where things are mocing that fast, proportionally, the walls would have to be out of this world to contain that muc energy and not dissolve. How does the cell wall do it?

And same question about organelles inside the cell.

Comment: What speeds and sizes do you take for the cells? It might demystify the amazement.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, the speed of molecules in air or a solution is [on the order of the local speed of sound](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/78879/simple-explanation-of-relation-between-speed-of-sound-and-r-m-s-speed). This is because they have kinetic energy *because* of the temperature. Each molecule has kinetic energy proportional to the ambient temperature (and hence velocity scaling as $\sqrt{T}$).

But the kinetic energy of a molecule is tiny because of the low mass. When objects in our everyday world move fast they have masses measured in kilograms. A protein molecule (say a hemoglobin subunit molecule at 16,000 Daltons) has a mass of $2.6\cdot 10^{-23}$ kg and correspondingly less kinetic energy at the same speed (for 1500 m/s, $2.925\cdot 10^{-17}$ J - and it would actually move more slowly due to its high mass).

What really matters is the relative kinetic energy between molecules (and other things like organelles) and the strength of the structures they bump into. Consider a cell wall; it has a stiffness on the order of 20 kPa. To indent it 1 nm requires $10^{-14}$ J: the above protein is a thousand times too light to do it.